# How to change JS, CSS and MySQL database depending on work environment?

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, development-environment, production-environment

In Heroku, how do I change what database my Sinatra app accesses depending on its environment?

That is: If `main.rb` is on my local machine, how do I get it to access `localhost`, but when I `git push` it to any branch on my Heroku repo, get it to access a live database?

Same for JS and CSS. If I'm working on my local machine, how would I set my app so that it accesses JS in `dev/js/script.js`, but when live it would access `live/js/script.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't usually have separate assets based on the environment you are running on. That can give you a small nightmare when you need update things.

How this usually works in Ruby land is that the server (Heroku etc) sets global [environment variables](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyfeatures/a/envvar.htm) when it runs your app. These variables & values are available in your app so you can check if you are running in production, testing etc.

Heroku automatically sets the DATABASE_URL environment variable and you can access it like so:

```
configure do
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(ENV['DATABASE_URL'])  
end
```

On each server the DATABASE_URL variable will be set accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should not have separate folder for different environments for js and css, and they should be put under assets folder: 
If you have a good reason to do so, you can use the following code:

```
set :root, File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))

configure :development do   
  set :public_folder, Proc.new { "#{root}/dev/assets" }
end

configure :production do 
  set :public_folder, Proc.new { "#{root}/live/assets" }
end
```

Then in the view, if you put javascripts under assets/javascript, you can link to them with the path `javascripts/filename.js`

Comment: I see. And it might be similar for database, too? That is, I'd make two separate `connectToDB.rb` files, and have a `configure` method for each?